# Selecting odds/even rows only in R using readxl

Tags: r, data-manipulation, readxl

My data are as follows:

```
id  name    age
1   a   45
2   b   47
3   a   49
4   b   51
5   a   53
6   b   55
7   a   57
8   b   59
9   a   61
```

In order to extract only the odds rows, I tried the following code:

```
read_excel("C:\\Users\\Patrick\\Desktop\\Age.xlsx", range = cell_rows(seq(1,10,2)), col_names = T)
```

But I was returned the following:

```
  # A tibble: 8 x 3
     id  name   age
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
1     1     a    45
2     2     b    47
3     3     a    49
4     4     b    51
5     5     a    53
6     6     b    55
7     7     a    57
8     8     b    59
```

Not quite what I wanted. **How can I obtain dataframe as follows**:

```
     id  name   age
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
1     1     a    45
3     3     a    49
5     5     a    53
7     7     a    57
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't seem like `read_excel` offers this functionality

```
read_excel(path, sheet = 1, col_names = TRUE, col_types = NULL, na = "", skip = 0)
```

You can subset after reading in the file with

```
df <- read_excel("C:\\Users\\Patrick\\Desktop\\Age.xlsx", col_names=T)
df[c(TRUE, FALSE),]     # for odd rows
df[c(FALSE, TRUE),]     # for even rows
```